# Jar file not loading

Tags: java, jar

I have jar file which is signed  on my local machine. Its working fine in local machine. When I upload it to the server it shows some error like

```
load: class com.trusm.tru.ReadNFCSerialNumber not found.
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.trusm.tru.ReadNFCSerialNumber
at sun.plugin2.applet.Applet2ClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadCode(Unknown Source)
at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2Manager.createApplet(Unknown Source)
at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2Manager$AppletExecutionRunnable.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: open HTTP connection failed:http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/popit/popit/com/trusm/tru/ReadNFCSerialNumber.class
at sun.plugin2.applet.Applet2ClassLoader.getBytes(Unknown Source)
at sun.plugin2.applet.Applet2ClassLoader.access$000(Unknown Source)
at sun.plugin2.applet.Applet2ClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
... 7 more
Exception: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.trusm.tru.ReadNFCSerialNumber
```

Can any one help me on this???

Comment: we are developers, not psychics. We can't guess what's the code with which you are including the applet in the html page.

Comment: Bozho, speak for yourself. How do you think I paid for college?

Comment: psst. you know the rules - it must remain secret.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the signing has caused the problems.

When i signed the jar in the server instead of my local machine it works like a charm...

Answer (score 1):

```
　open HTTP connection failed:　http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/popit/popit/com/trusm/tru/ReadNFCSerialNumber.class
```

Looks like a network problem.

Answer (score 0):

Might be you have added the jar using external refrences, Check that jar is available in the deployed folder or not or you may create lib folder into root folder and add jar there...

Answer (score 0):

Use the appletviewer on the HTML file you have created, as it gives much better insight into what goes on.

Answer (score 0):

The stack trace:

```
Caused by: java.io.IOException: open HTTP connection failed:http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/popit/popit/com/trusm/tru/ReadNFCSerialNumber.class
```

suggests that the HTTP path to ReadNFCSearialNumber.class doesn't exist. Try and put that URL link on the browser and if you get a HTTP 404, then you know that the path is the problem.

Other than that, we don't know how you structured your project, so we can't guess here.